# DataGridView - cell validation - prevent CurrentRow/Cell change

Tags: c#, winforms, validation

I have WinForms `DataGridView` with source set to `SortableBindingList`. In this form, there's column `Comment` and I need to prevent user from inserting some characters, thus validation.

What I want to do is, whenever user enters invalid value, system will notify him (`OnNotification( 'You entered wrong comment');`) and force him/her to stay in edit mode.

So far I build solution like this:

```
void MyDataGridView_CellEndEdit( object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e )
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == ColumnComment.Index) {
        object data = Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;
        if( (data != null) && (!CommentIsValid( data.ToString()))){
            CurrentCell = Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
            BeginEdit( true );

            // My notification method
            OnNotification( String.Format( "Comment `{0}` contains invalid characters) );
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I have following issues with this:

- `OnCellValidating` is triggered only when whole form is closing or when current row is changed, not after I finish editing of *single cell*, so I've put check into `CellEndEdit`.
- When I used `Enter`/`Esc` to end editing, it works as expected and desired.
- When I use mouse and click to another row, cell stays in edit mode, but another row gets selected.
- When I try to use `Enter` (displays notification on invalid comment) and then `Esc` (to cancel edit) it uses value *pushed* by `Enter` (because edit mode has finished).

**So my questions are**:

- How can I fire `CellValidating` after each cell edit, not when form is closing
- How can I prevent `CurrentRow` and `CurrentCell` change even after mouse click?
- How can I force cell to **stay** in edit mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I use mouse and click to another row, cell stays in edit mode, but another row gets selected.

Here I would use a global Boolean, `bool isInvalidState` say and a global `DataGridViewCell = invalidCell` object. In the default state you can set `isInvalidState = false` and `invalidCell = null`. Then using

```
private bool OnNotification(string cellValue)
{
    // Check for error.
    if (error)
        return false;
}
```

Then in the above method

```
void MyDataGridView_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == ColumnComment.Index) {
        object data = Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;
        if((data != null) && (!CommentIsValid(data.ToString()))){
            CurrentCell = Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
            BeginEdit(true);

            // My notification method
            isInvalidState = OnNotification(
                String.Format("Comment `{0}` contains invalid characters));
            if (isInvalidState)
                invalidCell = MyDataGridView[e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex];
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, wire-up an event `CellContentClick` on your `DataGridView` and check if `isInvalidState == true`

```
private void MyDataGridView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (isInvlaidState)
    {
        isInvalidState = false;
        MyDataGridView.CurrentCell = invalidCell;
        invalidCell = null;
        return;
    }
    // Do other stuff here.
}
```

> When I try to use Enter (displays notification on invalid comment) and then Esc (to cancel edit) it uses value pushed by Enter (because edit mode has finished).

I am not sure about this problem; it is likely you will have to handle the `KeyDown` event and capture the escape key - handling it differently.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work for me fully as the code in CellContentClick event handler never set the control back to the cell being validated for its value. Nevertheless, your hint of using global variables 'isInvalidState' and 'invalidCell' helped me construct another solution that works perfectly fine. I'll try to post my solution here soon.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. It shall work.

```
private void datagridview1_dataGridview_CellValidating
(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e) 
{
    if (datagridview1_dataGridview.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.Equals(""))
    {
         MessageBox.Show("Product name should not be empty", "Error");
         datagridview1_dataGridview.CurrentCell = datagridview1_dataGridview.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2];
         datagridview1_dataGridview.CurrentCell.Selected = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I mentioned in my question `OnCellValidating is triggered only when whole form is closing or when current row is changed, not after I finish editing of single cell, so I've put check into CellEndEdit.`, so unsless you can suggest how to fire CellValidating before edit mode is closed, this would work. Otherwise it's useless :(

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, MoonKnight's solution didn't work fully for me as the code in `CellContentClick` event handler never set the control back to the cell that was being validated for its value, when it had an invalid value. Nevertheless, considering his valuable hint of using global variables `isInvalidState` and `invalidCell` helped me constructing the following solution that works exactly as asked in the OP.

Using the combination of `CellValidating` and `CellValidated` in the right way solves the problem as follows:

Do your data validation inside the `CellValidating` event handler. Set the `isInvalidState` flag and the `cellWithInvalidUserInput` variable (NOTE: I renamed the `invalidCell` to `cellWithInvalidUserInput`):

```
private void MyDataGridView_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    var cellUnderConsideration = MyDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];

    if (!ValidateCurrentCellValue(cellUnderConsideration)) 
    {               
       OnNotification( String.Format( "Comment `{0}` contains invalid characters) );
       //Or MessageBox.Show("your custom message");

       isInvalidState = true;
       cellWithInvalidUserInput = cellUnderConsideration;
       e.Cancel = true;                    
    }
}
```

The data validation function:

```
bool isInvalidState;
DataGridViewCell cellWithInvalidUserInput;
private bool ValidateCurrentCellValue(DataGridViewCell cellToBeValidated)
{
    //return 'true' if valid, 'false' otherwise
}
```

Perform desired actions on UI controls inside the `CellValidated` event handler:

```
private void MyDataGridView_CellValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (isInvalidState)
    {
        isInvalidState = false;

        if (cellWithInvalidUserInput != null && cellWithInvalidUserInput.RowIndex > -1)
        {
            MyDataGridView.CurrentCell = cellWithInvalidUserInput;
            MyDataGridView.CurrentCell.Selected = true;
            MyDataGridView.BeginEdit(true);
        }

        cellWithInvalidUserInput = null;
    }
}
```